# how to set directories js for javascript files, ui for interfaces and css directory for style in web.xml

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to set web.xml for my first project. For managing project easily i want to arrange files in folders according to their extension in Web Content folder.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with just putting them in exactly those folders?

```
someapp/js/myscript.js
someapp/css/mystyles.css
```